Prove that the coefficient of equidistant terms in the expansion of $(1+x+x^{2})^{2}$ are equal.
The Actual Question:
If $$(1+x+x^{2})^{n} = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^{2}+\cdots+(a_{2n})x^{2n}$$ then $$(a_0+a_1+\cdots a_n)^{3}-(a_n +a_{n+1}+\cdots a_{2n})^{3}$$ is equal to?
Experience says that equidistant terms from first and last terms should have equal coefficients, however I'm unable to prove it. Any help is appreciated.

What did you try?

Does the binomial theorem not get you anywhere...? That would be my first idea to try.

Just plug in 1 in the polynomial expression. That gives you the sum of all coefficient

@Gwen Tried doing that but that doesn't get us anywhere, except for providing the value of sum of coefficients.

@RedFive Nothing conclusive was obtained on using the binomial theorem

It may be easier to instead consider the expansion $$\begin{align}\left(x^{-1}+1+x\right)^n&=x^{-n}\left(1+x+x^2\right)^n\\&=a_0x^{-n}+a_1x^{-n+1}+\cdots+a_n+\cdots+a_{2n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{2n}x^n&(1)\end{align}$$Now consider $\left(u^{-1}+1+u\right)^n$, where $u=x^{-1}$. By definition, $$\begin{align}\left(u^{-1}+1+u\right)^n=a_0u^{-n}+a_1u^{-n+1}+\cdots+a_n+\cdots+a_{2n-1}u^{n-1}+a_{2n}u^n\end{align}$$Substituting $x=u^{-1}$ back into the equation gives$$\begin{align}\left(x+1+x^{-1}\right)^n&=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots a_n+\cdots+a_{2n-1}x^{-n+1}+a_{2n}x^{-n}&(2)\end{align}$$By comparing coefficients of $(1)$ and $(2)$ it is easy to see that $a_k=a_{2n-k}$, so to answer the original question, $$(a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n)^3-(a_n+a_{n+1}+a_{2n})^3=0$$
